# MagicDraw 18.3 developing plugins using Eclipse 4.5.2.M

Tags: eclipse, plugins, magic-draw

I am having trouble configurating Eclipse for MD 18.3 plugin development.

I have thoroughly followed the "MagicDraw 18.3 Developer Guide / Development in Eclipse" tutorial you can find inside MagicDraw\openapi section to set up Eclipse.

When launching *MagicDraw with all plugins* run configuration, it throws the following error and terminates:

`!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.variables 4 120 2016-07-20 10:39:12.159
!MESSAGE Reference to undefined variable file_uri`

caused by this line of the run configuration

```
-Dosgi.framework.extensions=reference:${file_uri:${workspace_loc:/MagicDraw/MAGIC_DRAW_INSTALL_DIRECTORY/lib/bundles}}/com.nomagic.magicdraw.osgi.fragment
```

However, \lib\bundles\com.nomagic.magicdraw.osgi.fragment_1.0.0.201601271815.jar
 is existing

I'm running the demo license, but that shouldn't influence the configuration. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Solved this issue, by replacing `reference:${file_uri:${workspace_loc:/MagicDraw/MAGIC_DRAW_INSTALL_DIRECTORY/lib/bundles}}/com.nomagic.magicdraw.osgi.fragment` with the actual path and **enabling com.nomagic.magicdraw.platform.feature** in the bundles tab of the run configuration.

**Next Problem:** The provided example plugins won't load, throwing

`java.lang.NullPointerException    at com.nomagic.magicdraw.plugins.XMLPluginDescriptorLoader.loadPluginDescriptorData(XMLPluginDescriptorLoader.java:172)`

and therefore

```
ERROR PLUGINS - Failed to create plugin: My Plug-in 2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myplugin2.MyPlugin2
```

Same message for both, the example plugins and my own plugin. I have checked the plugin.xml files and also experimentally enabled the run configurations > bundles > workspace checkbox.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't like `${file_uri`, what is telling you to use that?

Comment: It is part of the .launch configuration file, which I am told to use by the tutorial.

Comment: Give us a link to where this is in the tutorial, I am not going to find it and read it all.

Comment: [development in Eclipse](http://docs.nomagic.com/display/MD184/Development+in+Eclipse) is for MD 18.4 beta but it is the same as for 18.3. When you follow the tutorial, the ambiguous .launch file is located inside the _MagicDraw with all plugins_ folder.

Comment: Did a partial fix by replacing the reference by the actual path. MD starts now, but it is not able to create or open a project..

Comment: .. throwing ```java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.nomagic.uml2.impl.magicdraw.auxiliaryconstructs.mdmodels.ModelClassImpl.createModel(ModelClassImpl.java:85) ...
``` maybe this Question is going into another direction

Comment: Are you aware that you can email support@nomagic.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a new clean Eclipse installation solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit this line:

```
- Dosgi.framework.extensions=com.nomagic.magicdraw.osgi.fragment
```

Comment: Did a partial fix by replacing the reference by the actual path. MD starts now, but it is not able to create or open a project..